# Questions on questions stemming from a read of Effective C++

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

On a journey toward glorious ascending enlightenment in C++, I have sailed my schooner along the river that is Meyer's *Effective C++*. Now, at the banks of rest and reflection, my mind is plump with the pressure of escaping questions. Questions which I must ask before the energetic interrogative phrasing destroys my skull as a melon would explode when injected with too much alcohol via syringe.

Some concern the language of C++ itself. While others refer to the actual text.

I ask of thee, fellow programmers, you great minds, you tall glasses of water, on your advice on the best cause and course to broach these subjects on this site.

One might say to post the questions separately. Others may hint at grouping them, making use of Meyer's uncanny point numbers.

Should one also assume that others have indeed read this book? Would, or could (or *should*), one use it to establish the setting on which one's question is based? Or do I provide excerpts to go with my questions for those in the crowd that may not have come across this world-shattering publication?

Comment: You should make a separate post for each question you want to ask. It's best to provide excerpts for the benefit of those who don't have access to the book. _This_ question itself, like others have mentioned, should be asked on meta. :-P

Answer (score 4):

- Make each question individually. One
  question per question.
- As you type, check the suggestions
  for duplicate questions.
- Put the question in your own words.
  Mention the source of your
  questionings at the end of each post.
- Don't assume that others have read this book. You'd be surprised at home many people have not read the same books as you.

Comment: I'd expect a large number of C++ programmers to be familiar with the book, but certainly not all of them.  (I'd recommend it heartily to most of those who aren't.)